# Laravel initializing vuejs for new project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

After installing fresh installation of `Laravel` i installed `VueRouter` and after implementing simple code for that such as below, i can't use `VueJs` and i don't get any error in terminal:

commands don't show any error and i get `build successful` from `Laravel` mix
`/resources/js/app.js` content:

[GITHUB project link](https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/laravel-vuejs):

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent";

require('./bootstrap');


const routes = new VueRouter(
    {
        mode:'history',
        routes:[
            {
                path:'/',
                component:ExampleComponent
            }
        ]
    }
);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    routes
});
```

`/resources/js/bootstrap.js` content:

```js
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

`app.blade.php` content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`welcome.blade.php` content:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
@endsection
```

laravel `web.php` content:

```php
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any','.*');
```

simple piece of laravel `composer.json`:

```json
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.2"
},
```

`webpack.mix.js` content:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and then:

```
php artisan serve && npm run watch
```

i have empty page after navigating to `/` in browser `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

how can i resolve this issue to use `vuejs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning Vue router, what I usually have is a separated **router.js** file because it can be lengthy:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
...
Vue.use(Router)
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'users',
      component: () => import('./views/users/_users.vue'),
    }
    ...
 ]

 export default router
```

And in **main.js** I have:

```
import router from './router' // path to router.js file
...
Vue.router = router
...

export default new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: what are `store` and `render` in your code?

Comment: `store` is for Vuex I forgot to remove it I apologize, about render https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-does-render-h-h-app-mean/53313 expand the answer to see it fully

Comment: thanks so much, i have `laravel` with `vuejs` now

Comment: I'm glad it helped.. good luck at that and enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

These [constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) are appearently superfluous: `->where('any','.*')`.

And the route might not match - or [`.htaccess`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) might be absent;
eg. to capture regex `(.*)` into variable `$page` for `any` method:

```
Route::any('(.*)', function($page) {
    // dd($page);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Not sure, but you probably also need to `Vue.use(VueRouter)`; the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) also initialize differently:

```
const app = new Vue({routes}).$mount('#app')
```

I mean, there is no debug information and there are even two ways how to install VueRouter.